# Best way to export a Job application to a client for easy editing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, adobe-creative-suite, microsoft-office

This is my first topic, so go easy on me. :D

I got a customer who wants me to design her job application. I want to design it with Adobe illustrator and set up the text with indesign. However the client does not own copies of these programs, which then leads me to the question:

How should I export the final product for my client, so that it is easy to edit in the future. Either for Microsoft office, or maybe by some easy freeware program?

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll have to make it in word if you want to preserve editing. Indesign is for final layouts really. It helps to make a indesign draft though and then try to match that in my experience.

Comment: Wow that's disappointing, and really kinda weird. I can't be the first who's encountered this type of problem.

Comment: You are not. But this goes for a lot of specialized software. Making something that you can then edit without the software it created will be a hassle in any field.

Comment: In my job I consistently need to provide the design _editable_. What I do is, for example, in a design for A4, I create a Microsoft Office's Word file, put the image in background and creates text-boxes. In the case of using fonts that was bought or even designed for me, I add an extra-fee for Copyright purposes. :)

Comment: You mean like setting the whole thing up in word first, then do the layouts after, and then merge it all together in the end?

Comment: @KMSTR I don't recommend that workflow, primarily because the client will see something you can only do in InDesign and then insist it should look exactly like that in Word. Begin as you mean to go on. If the end product has to be in Word, start designing in Word, so you respect its limitations.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice! I just think it's incredible that I am so limited in layouting this type of assignments. Are there any alternative software that you know off, that are easy to use and perhaps even free, that would actually work with the problem I'm facing?

Comment: Yes I wouldn't show an indesign layout to a client either if I have to deliver in word. But being used to draft in indesign I would start there to get a basis I am looking for.

Comment: There's only one thing you should master for designing in word processors, and that's tables, tables and more tables. Its the only way to ensure consistency of positioning across the word processors like Microsoft Word, Open Office and Google Docs.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an old topi, I have no idea if this is still relevant but I thought I could give it shot.

You can still design in InDesign. You can edit PDF text in Acrobat. 
All you have to do is export the design, with lorem ipsum or whatever text you like, as a PDF.

Your client can open it and then start to edit text in Arobat, or maybe even Reader.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to make the comments an answer, shall we. Feel free to edit.

First of all find out what software your client uses and what version (for example newer word files can embed pdf as images). Then you need to, preferably if at all possible, use that same version.

Design in the same application as the client will be using, othervise you risk not being able to replicate it in target application. There is a reason why word is no InDesign, its just missing a lot of functionality, so manage expectations. You can still despite all this get good results, and learn something in the process.

You need to work with your limitations, dont go moping around what you could do if the systen was better. This is not conductive, a true craftsman does not blame his tools. You can use tables or textboxes, but be sure to test this thoroughly if your not used to working in target application.